# Wordpress paginate links not working for custom queries

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I use a template part named 'product_links' to get the links to all posts in a particular subcategory of a parent category and with a specific tag. The template part is accessed from category.php and single.php. The template part returns ordered-list. Here is the code.

```
<?php
      if(is_single()){
        $category = get_the_category();
        $parent = get_cat_name($category[0]->category_parent);
      }
      else{
          $parent=wp_title('',false);
      }
      $qvar=( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $posts_q=new WP_Query(array(
                'category_name'=>$parent,
                'mid_size' => 2,
                'posts_per_page'=>3,
                'paged'=>$qvar,
                'tag__in'=>array(get_tag_ID('products'))
      ));
      if ($posts_q->have_posts()){
                while ($posts_q->have_posts()){
                          $posts_q->the_post();
                          ?>
                          <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> </li>
                          <?php
                }
                echo paginate_links(array('total'=>$posts_q->max_num_pages));
      } else{ echo "No Products";}
      wp_reset_query();
```

The code works properly if called from category.php and fails when called from single.php.

Comment: Your code throws all kinds of errors, amongst them a fatal error for a non-existent function `get_tag_ID()`. Pls. fix and update question.

Comment: get_tag_ID is a custom function which return the id if tag name is given. i defined that function in functions.php